# Table based on csv data not updating properly d3js v4

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In [**This**](https://plnkr.co/edit/8FkmQgHnXskuEvv3JIMy?p=preview) table I'm filtering through data in the `filter` function that updates the table with a new array that the filter function provides.

There doesn't appear to be anything wrong with the filtered array being passed through to the `update` function so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong in the `update` section and I can't figure out what's wrong with it

I've looked through [other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18032229/7473025) answers and tried doing it that way but they are all based on d3js v3 so the logic isn't compatible with v4 as far is I can see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need just two small changes in your code:

1) Move `rows.exit().remove()` **before** `enter` method:

```
var rows = tbody.selectAll('tr')
  .data(dataNew, d => d.name);

rows.exit().remove(); // <== !!!

rows = rows
  .enter()
  .append('tr')
  .merge(rows);
```

2) Append text for `tdRow` **after** merge:

```
tdRow = tdRow
  .enter()
  .append('td')
  .merge(tdRow)
  .text(d => d.value) // <== !!!
```

Check [updated plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/lLdjgdoJBSvwgkyhnjTM?p=preview)